# Mathematical phantoms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The field with one element or characteristic one ($\mathbb{F_1}$ or $\mathbb{F_{un}}$) is a mathematical phantom, which can defined as a beast who  clearly (i.e. within the current mathematical framework) does not exist, but there are many pointers in a direction that it should.

Are there other examples of mathematical phantoms ?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but there are "phantom maps" in algebraic topology : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_map

Comment: I think, *phantom* is not the right word about the idea of a field with $1$ element, arising in Mochizuki's work. In number theory there are always such "ideas", which later obtain a precise defintion, such as a ["motive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motive_(algebraic_geometry)). So these are just new mathematical concepts.

Comment: As a quick remark, here is a fun paper by Alain Connes, Caterina Consani, and Matilde Marcolli about $\mathbb{F}_1$; it's called [Fun with $\mathbb{F}_1$](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/funBC.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dietrich (in the comments) that the meaning of "mathematical phantom" is not entirely clear. In particular, the demarcation from merely very fruitful abstractions is blurry; perhaps useful criteria are:

- There should be a statement which was held to be obviously true before the discovery of the phantom, but which is false in view of the new concept.
- It should have required a nontrivial effort to make it precise (to "help it come into being").
- It should have great explanatory power and vast consequences ([Gavin Wraith](http://www.wra1th.plus.com/gcw/math/MathPhant.html): "which [...] obtrudes its effects so convincingly that one is forced to concede a broader notion of existence", sorry for linking to http).

Phantoms in this stricter sense could include:

- The irrational numbers. (Running counter to the basic tenet "all is number" by the Pythagorean school, where by "number" they meant "rational number".)
- The complex numbers. (The idea of a number squaring to $-1$ was surely held to be obviously nonsensically.)
- The $p$-adic numbers.
- Actual infinity, together with the flexible notion of sets we have nowadays (vastly surpassing recursive subsets of $\mathbb{N}$) and the axiom of choice.
- Sobolev function spaces.
- Infinitesimal numbers.

Phantoms in a broader sense (where I can't think of any held-to-be-obviously-true statement falsified by them) could include:

- Symmetries of zeros of polynomials, or more generally groups.
- The field with one element.
- Ideals in number theory.
- Motives.
- $\infty$-categories.
- Toposes. (Generalizing and unifying various cohomology theories.)
- Nonclassical logics. (Born in the foundational crisis, nowadays with lots of applications in mainstream mathematics.)